# Applying JQuery functions to custom class types?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I have a series of divs with an "event_id" of some random text pulling from my database that is temporarily stored into an array on the client-side. My goal is to loop through each of these ids and disable any onclick events associated with the divs with said event_id.

## Example:

```
    for (x = 0; x < google_ids.length; x++) {
        $('event_id' + google_ids[x]).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() ;
        });
    }
```

I'm trying something close to this. Obvious issue is that the class type? is an event_id, not a regular class and I'm not sure how I go about handling that. Each string iD is stored in the google_ids array.

Comment: $('[event_id='+google_ids[x]+']')

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm still wondering how to disable the event_id div as well. The code I have listed above doesn't do what I want it to. It is still draggable, clickable, etc.

Comment: Are you using jquery UI to do the draggable?

Comment: you can use `return false` instead of  `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @RLam I'm using this massive 3rd party JS library DHTMLX Scheduler

Comment: @AtikurRahman Even hardcoding something like $('[event_id="f6av3mn7chjc827ra497b8g178"]').unbind("click"); allows me to drag and click the item

Comment: you can try...`for (x = 0; x < google_ids.length; x++) {
        $('[event_id=' + google_ids[x]).on('mousedown',function(e) {
            return false;
        });
    }`

Comment: @AtikurRahman ok it seems to disable it initially, but then after clicking again, it's clickable

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @AtikurRahman There's unfortunately too much code in the library running a majority of the system. I thought it would be easier to fix, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: @RyanShocker You should read the documentation of `DHTMLX Scheduler`. http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onbeforedrag_event.html

Answer (score 2):

Selector should be `[event_id="whatever"]`, so use:

```
 for (x = 0; x < google_ids.length; x++) {
        $('[event_id="' + google_ids[x] + '"]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() ;
        });
    }
```

By the way, better way would be to use the class `.dhx_cal_event`, if you can use this and only required set of elements hold this, or modify your code use `data-event_id` instead of `event_id`  class as `event_id` is not a valid `HTML5` attribute.

**To remove click event:**

```
for (x = 0; x < google_ids.length; x++) {
            $('[event_id="' + google_ids[x] + '"]').unbind("click");
        }
```

Comment: e.preventDefault isn't disabling the movement, draggability and click events on the element. Any ideas?

Comment: same issue, I can still click and move the item

Comment: @RyanShocker check the updated code

Comment: Very strange, can still drag and do everything. I even hardcoded from the example above. $('[event_id="f6av3mn7chjc827ra497b8g178"]').unbind("click");

Comment: You using `jquery-ui`, can you create a fiddle to replicate your issue?